# Change center of Vignette in Apple Photos

Tags: apple-aperture, apple, iphoto

Is it possible to change the center of a Vignette in Apple Photos? Until now I used Lightroom and there it is possible.
Or is there a Add-on or extension that can provide this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the center of the vignetting tool in Apple Photos does not appear to be possible. The available settings are: Strength, Radius, Softness.

[image: screenshot]